HTTP ERROR 500 on Laravel Vite 11 when Deploy to Shared Hosting
I use 000Webhost as my web-shared hosting.
My folder structure looks like this:

I've changed my Composer Autoloader directory and this is my index.php looks like:
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

// Determine if the application is in maintenance mode...
if (file_exists($maintenance = __DIR__.'/../laravel/storage/framework/maintenance.php')) {
    require $maintenance;
}

// Register the Composer autoloader...
require __DIR__.'/../laravel/vendor/autoload.php';

// Bootstrap Laravel and handle the request...
(require_once __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/app.php')
    ->handleRequest(Request::capture());

I use sqlite and local storage for my database, This is my .env.
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=mykey
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_TIMEZONE=UTC
APP_URL=http://localhost

APP_LOCALE=en
APP_FALLBACK_LOCALE=en
APP_FAKER_LOCALE=en_US

APP_MAINTENANCE_DRIVER=file
APP_MAINTENANCE_STORE=database

BCRYPT_ROUNDS=12

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_STACK=single
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
# DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
# DB_PORT=3306
# DB_DATABASE=laravel
# DB_USERNAME=root
# DB_PASSWORD=

SESSION_DRIVER=database
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
SESSION_ENCRYPT=false
SESSION_PATH=/
SESSION_DOMAIN=null

BROADCAST_CONNECTION=log
FILESYSTEM_DISK=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=database

CACHE_STORE=database
CACHE_PREFIX=

MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1

REDIS_CLIENT=phpredis
REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=log
MAIL_HOST=127.0.0.1
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="hello@example.com"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=
AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT=false

VITE_APP_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

Do i need to run "php artisan run build" first? and do i need to move my css, js, views folders from resources to public folder?
did i miss something? this is my 1st time deploying laravel to shared hosting, anything would help, thanks in advance

check in log  file .

did you install laravel via composer or uploaded the vendor dir on your own?

@Alex i uploaded to the vendor dir, did i do it in wrong way? cause 000Webhost doesn't provide a terminal in free mode

@Alex does laravel often need terminal in its shared hosting provider?

@mimie i am not sure if you can install it/ get it running without composer at all. edit: well uploading the vendor manually should do it, so maybe check your error logs to see what is not working

did you actually put in your database auth data in your .env file?

APP_URL=http://localhost will need to be changed.

@Olivier but that wouldnt cause a 500

@Alex I didn't say that. It was just a side note.

Please share more details, like the full and exact error message, the code triggering this error, and your attempts to resolve the problem

@Alex sorry i dont understand sir, i use local storage to save data for this mini-self project

@LalitKumar edit: thankyou for suggesting, so i checked my log file and it turns out that i had verification email problem, besides, i just found out that the main problem is because of files size limitation so that some folders cant be uploaded. now i'll try to fix it by using ftp clients because it doesnt restrict the limitations

@Olivier thankyou, i missed that, and i just changed it

I've wasted hours on this.
Just remove LOG_STACK from .env
It's an L10 directive and when kept inside .env after an upgrade it will create many problems in multiple places of the app.

been a while, but dude thanks

No worries.
This is the most common problem while migrating to L11, people tend to forget to remove these 2 settings which breaks everything usually:
LOG_STACK
and
MAIL_DRIVER.
They're marked as obsolete and deprecated but should actually be marked as "breaking changes".
